# Как сделать 4 колонки?

Tags: css

Во всех уроках по 3 колонки, а как сделать 4?

```
.leftColumn {
    width: 300px;
    float: left;
    background: #3d2af0;
    padding-bottom: 20000px;
    margin-bottom: -20000px;
}

.centerColumn {
    width: 600px;
    float: left;
    background: #e34456;
    padding-bottom: 20000px;
    margin-bottom: -20000px;
}

.rightColumn {
    width: 10px;
    float: left;
    background: #e3e244;
    padding-bottom: 20000px;
    margin-bottom: -20000px;
}
```

Вот пробовал данным способом, три колонки получилось, а как начал делать 4, нет.

Comment: ну и что за колонка у тебя

    .rightColumn {
        width: 10px;
    }

10 пикселов шириной?

Comment: ты ещё кусок HTML приложи

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- http://www.abdesign.kiev.ua/ru/ckrvdf/
- http://test-templates.com/blog/51-rezinovaya-blochnaya-verstka-v-4-stolbca.html  ([пример](http://test-templates.com/development/4colonki/index.html))
- взять двухколоночный пример и каждую колонку поделить ещё на две

---

Обрати внимание на сетки в популярных фрейворках:

- [Twitter Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/grid/)
- [Semantic UI](http://semantic-ui.com/collections/grid.html)

Даже если не будете использоваться передовой опыт человечества, загляните в CSS - их сетки весьма хороши.

Comment: Недавно один товарищ делал меню боковое, выезжающее слева. Сначала хотел закодить на чистом JS, потом на jquery, потом плагин для jquery нашёл и в итоге дело закончилось вот такой строкой javascript на всю страницу + semantic ui:

    $('#button').on('click', function() { $('.sidebar').sidebar('toggle'); });

Коротко, просто, надёжно.

Он расстроился. Я напомнил анекдот про мужика, который взял $1000 за то, что стукнул молотком по мотору и тот заработал. Из них $999 за то, что знал, куда стукнуть. Ценность данной строки - $999 за знание, как сделать так, чтобы работало.

Comment: уточнил ответ

Answer (score 2):

Это будет не совсем ответ видимо. Если я правильно понял что вы хотите разложить основные элементы по страницу (например меню слева, контент по центру, и ещё две колонки справа под что-то второстепенное).

Совсем кроссбраузерно, с поддержкой всяких там IE6 это делается через различные сложносочинённые финты ушами. Но чем дальше тем лучше. Со временем в CSS появлялись всё новые инструменты облегчающие эту задачу.

Сейчас почти во всех браузерах есть поддержка инлайновых блоков (display: inline-block), это такой блочные (как <div>) элемент который в некоторых отношениях ведёт себя как текстовый (инлайновый, например <span>) элемент.

Инлайновые блоки выстраиваются друг за другом в строку (а не друг над другом как блочные элементы), если места не хватает то они переносятся. травишь подряд n инлайновых элементов, задаёшь каждому ширину 100/n и получаешь n колонок, в общем красота.

С ними есть свои тонкости (например пробелы между инлайновыми элементами это тоже элементы, они занимают место и взрывают мозги новичкам пытающимся понять почему два элемента шириной 100 пикселей не влезают в блок шириной в 200 пикселей).

Но человечество на этом не остановилось. Сумрачные гении HTML-верстки из W3C и Microsoft придумали два стандарта каждый из которых был призван окончательно решить вопрос раскладки элементов по экрану.

Стандарт MS — [Grid](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-grid-layout/) реализован только в IE 10 и выше, сам стандарт находится в стадии рабочего черновика W3C. Кажется есть обзорная статья на хабре. Стандарт от W3C (не знаю кто именно его разрабатывал) называется [flexbox](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-flexbox/) (aka flex, aka box) и он един в трёх лицах.

Существует по меньшей мере три распространённые версии (кажется два черновика и один релиз-кандидат). Самый цимес в том что версии эти сильно отличаются (первая распространённая версия весьма скромна возможностями, последняя — весьма наворочена) и далеко не все авторы всевозможных татуриалов (и прочих статей, текстов и постов) удосуживаются уточнить о какой версии они говорят. Так-же могут быть сложности с тем что-бы понять какие браузеры какую версию поддерживают. В общем бардак и хавос. Но когда пыль уляжется будет круто.

P.S. подробнее про финты ушами с раскладками и прочим смежным можно послушать например в этих лекциях:

http://tech.yandex.ru/education/shri/msk-2013/talks/1548/

http://tech.yandex.ru/education/shri/msk-2013/talks/1552/

http://tech.yandex.ru/education/shri/msk-2013/talks/1556/

Answer (score 0):

/*в параграф поместите ваш текст*/

```
p {
-moz-column-count: 4;
-moz-column-gap: 20px;
-webkit-column-count: 4;
-webkit-column-gap: 20px;
column-count: 4;
column-gap: 20px;
```

}

Comment: Можно поподробней?

Comment: Я так понял @lifting нужно раскладку страницы сделать (ну там справа меню, по центру контент, слева ещё что-то). А то что вы предлагаете это про то как один текстовый блок в n-колонок сверстать (как в печатных изданиях любят делать). К тому-же поддерживаете это не везде.

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="one">1</div>
    <div id="two">2</div>
    <div id="three">3</div>
    <div id="four">4</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
*{padding: 0; margin: 0;}
html, body{
    font: 12px Tahoma, sans-serif;
    min-height: 100%; 
    height: 100%;
}
#wrapper{
    width: 100%; 
    height: 100%; 
}
#wrapper:after{
    content: " ";
    display: block;
    height: 0;
    clear: both;
}
#wrapper > div{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 25%;
    min-height: 100%;
}

#one{
    float: left;
    background: #f00;
}
#two{
    float: left;
    background: #f30;
}
#three{
    float: right;
    background: #f90;
}
#four{
    float: right;
    background: #f60;
}
```

[Пример](http://jsfiddle.net/dekameron/4T8EW/)